# How to export per-file build times from Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Xcode displays nice per-file build/analyze times in its build log.

Unfortunately, when exporting or copying from the build log, I can't see those times anywhere.

**Is there a way to get per-file build/analyze times from either Xcode or the `xcodebuild` command-line tool** such that I can read them outside of Xcode or feed them to another program?

Please note that I am *not* asking about Swift-only compile times or summaries of entire build phases.

[image: Screenshot of Xcode build log]